# WxWidgets - ToggleButton with condition

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, togglebutton

What I would like to do is to add a condition for the button to toggle, if the condition isn't met the button does nothing. I tried to create this setting with a normal wxwidgets button first but couldn't find an easy way to change the style of the button after my condition was met.

Comment: wxWindow::Enable(bool enabled)

Comment: @JonTrauntvein From the documentation it doesn't seem to do what I want it to do. Currently I check the condition for the toggle in the "wxEVT_COMMAND_TOGGLEBUTTON_CLICKED" event handler, if I were to disable the togglebutton I couldn't check the condition for it any more.

Comment: Have you tried inheritance and overwriting the event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not pretty I fixed it by setting the togglebutton value through the SetValue(bool) function and set it to false to un-toggle the button if the condition failed:

```
void MyButton::onPressed(wxCommandEvent& event) {
    if (CONDITION) {
        SetValue(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most elegant solution for this kind of problems is to define a `wxEVT_UPDATE_UI` handler for the button which would disable it if some condition is true. E.g., assuming you can use C++11:

```
myButton->Bind(wxEVT_UPDATE_UI, [=](wxUpdateUIEvent& event) {
    event.Enable( some-condition-for-the-button-to-make-sense );
});
```

wxWidgets will call the defined event handler after any change in the UI and update the state of the button automatically.

This is preferable to managing the button state manually as it's very easy to forget to update it, especially if the condition is complicated and/or depends on the values of several other controls.